# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have hosted my site on GoDaddy server. It was working fine from last 2 years but suddenly I started getting error while login:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()
```

This is my login code snippet:

```
$unsafe_username = $_POST["username"];
$unsafe_password = md5($_POST["password"]);
$query = "select user_id from users where user_name= ? and password= ?";

$getdata=mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
$getdata->bind_param("ss", $unsafe_username, $unsafe_password);
$getdata->execute();
$getdata = $getdata->get_result();
$getdata = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata);
```

I am getting error in following line:

```
$getdata = $getdata->get_result();
```

This code was working for last 2 years but I started getting the above mentioned error from last 2 days. I call GoDaddy so many times, but they every time say that this is a coding issue.

I have no idea what to do now? Can anybody please help me out. I am clueless and frustrated.

Comment: u need to install mysqlnd. get_result is available only if mysqlnd is installed

Comment: Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php#105802

Comment: @vSugumar - I called Godaddy about it. But they are saying its already installed.

Comment: a work around would be after `execute()`,  to call `fetch()` then `bind_result($user_id)`

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale - can you please elaborate? I didn't get you.

Comment: Probably because `nd_mysqli` is not enabled but `mysqli` is

Comment: @IsThisJavascript - How can I verify it? Should I call Godaddy for this?

Comment: You can check the contents of [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). I doubt godaddy will make this change for you unless you have a dedicated server.. A solution provided in the duplicate has a nice quick fix.

Comment: execute print_r(get_loaded_extensions()) and check the result if you have mysqlnd if not u need to speak with your hosting provider... if it is a vps you can install it.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript - Which is the solution in the duplicate?

Comment: The code provided by Stefan S. is a nice copy + paste but for your own learning experience I recommend understanding how to use the fetch() and bind_result()

Comment: @IsThisJavascript - I could not understand how to fit his code in mine?

Comment: Godaddy?  Friends don't let friends ....